# What are some methods I can use to detect robots?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Just because software is automated doesn't mean it will abide by your robots.txt.
What are some methods available to detect when someone is crawling or DDOSing your website? Assume your site has 100s of 1000s of pages and is worth crawling or DDOSing.

Here's a dumb idea I had that probably doesn't work: give each user a cookie with a unique value, and use the cookie to know when someone is making second/third/etc requests. This probably doesn't work because crawlers probably don't accept cookies, and thus in this scheme a robot will look like a new user with each request.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put links in your pages that are not visible, or clickable by end-users. Many bots just follow all links. Once someone requests one of those links you almost certainly have a crawler/robot.

Comment: This is best practice IMO.  +1.

Comment: this is clever. how would you identify requests coming from the same bot after you've identified it? IP address and header info? I guess there isn't much else we can do..

Answer (score 1):

Project Honey Pot keeps a list of 'bad' bots.

Here's a class I wrote to contact their web-service.  You'll have to modify it some since I have a couple proprietary libs in it, but mostly it should be good to go.  Sometimes their service sends back errors, but it does help cut down on some of the bad traffic.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using SeaRisenLib2.Text;
using XmlLib;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HoneyPot
/// </summary>
public class HoneyPot
{
    private const string KEY = "blacklistkey"; // blacklist key - need to register at httpbl.org to get it
    private const string HTTPBL = "dnsbl.httpbl.org"; // blacklist lookup host
public HoneyPot()
{
}

public static Score GetScore_ByIP(string ip)
{
    string sendMsg = "", receiveMsg = "";
    int errorCount = 0; // track where in try/catch we fail for debugging
    try
    {
        // for testing: ip = "188.143.232.31";
        //ip = "173.242.116.72";
        if ("127.0.0.1" == ip) return null; // localhost development computer
        IPAddress address;
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out address))
            throw new Exception("Invalid IP address to HoneyPot.GetScore_ByIP:" + ip);
        errorCount++; // 1
        string reverseIP = ip.ToArray('.').Reverse().ToStringCSV(".");
        sendMsg = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", KEY, reverseIP, HTTPBL);
        errorCount++; // 2
        //IPHostEntry value = Dns.GetHostByName(sendMsg);
        IPHostEntry value = Dns.GetHostEntry(sendMsg);
        errorCount++; // 3
        address = value.AddressList[0];
        errorCount++; // 4
        receiveMsg = address.ToString();
        errorCount++; // 5
        int[] ipArray = receiveMsg.ToArray('.').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
        errorCount++; // 6
        if (127 != ipArray[0]) // error
            throw new Exception("HoneyPot error");
        errorCount++; // 7
        Score score = new Score()
        {
            DaysSinceLastSeen = ipArray[1],
            Threat = ipArray[2],
            BotType = ipArray[3]
        };
        errorCount++; // 8
        return score;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Using("VisitorLog/HoneyPotErrors", log =>
        {
            log.SetString("IPrequest", ip);
            log.SetString("SendMsg", sendMsg, XmlFile.ELEMENT);
            log.SetString("RecvMsg", receiveMsg, XmlFile.ELEMENT);
            log.SetString("Exception", ex.Message, XmlFile.ELEMENT);
            log.SetString("ErrorCount", errorCount.ToString());
        });
    }
    return null;
}

// Bitwise values
public enum BotTypeEnum : int
{
    SearchEngine = 0,
    Suspicious = 1,
    Harvester = 2,
    CommentSpammer = 4
}

public class Score
{
    public Score()
    {
        BotType = -1;
        DaysSinceLastSeen = -1;
        Threat = -1;
    }

    public int DaysSinceLastSeen { get; internal set; }
    public int Threat { get; internal set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Use BotTypeEnum to understand value.
    /// </summary>
    public int BotType { get; internal set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert HoneyPot Score values to String (DaysSinceLastSeen.Threat.BotType)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}",
            DaysSinceLastSeen,
            Threat,
            BotType);
    }

    public static explicit operator XElement(Score score)
    {
        XElement xpot = new XElement("HoneyPot");
        if (null != score)
        {
            if (score.DaysSinceLastSeen >= 0)
                xpot.SetString("Days", score.DaysSinceLastSeen);
            if (score.Threat >= 0)
                xpot.SetString("Threat", score.Threat);
            if (score.BotType >= 0)
                xpot.SetString("Type", score.BotType);
            foreach (BotTypeEnum t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(BotTypeEnum)))
            {
                // Log enum values as string for each bitwise value represented in score.BotType
                int value = (int)t;
                if ((value == score.BotType) || ((value & score.BotType) > 0))
                    xpot.GetCategory(t.ToString());
            }
        }
        return xpot;
    }

    public static explicit operator Score(XElement xpot)
    {
        Score score = null;
        if (null != xpot)
            score = new Score()
            {
                DaysSinceLastSeen = xpot.GetInt("Days"),
                Threat = xpot.GetInt("Threat"),
                BotType = xpot.GetInt("Type")
            };
        return score;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Log score value to HoneyPot child Element (if score not null).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="score"></param>
/// <param name="parent"></param>
public static void LogScore(HoneyPot.Score score, XElement parent)
{
    if ((null != score) && (null != parent))
    {
        parent.Add((XElement)score);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Though technically, it would not "detect" bot crawlers, I have an interesting way to block them. My method is to create an IIS filter or Apache plug-in. What you would do is encrypt all your html, asp, php, etc... pages. The only page not encrypted would be the index page. The index page simply installs a cookie with an encrypted public key, then redirects to a second index page. The IIS filter or Apache plug-in would then check each vistor to make sure they have this cookie. If it does, the filter would decrypt the requested page, then pass the page onto the web server for processing.

This method would allow a normal vistor to view your web page, but if a bot, which rejects cookies, tried to read your pages, they would all be encrypted.

Comment: and if your user, or their company policy, rejects cookies?

Comment: How about somebody who gets a link to one of the pages within the website and goes directly to it without passing through the index? What if they bookmark a page inside the website, and go back to it when the cookie has expired, without passing through the index?

Comment: @griegs - Then the company or user would get nothing but encrypted data.

Comment: @EdoDodo - Maybe the URL would have the key encrypted in the query parameters maybe? Its a work in progress lol

Comment: this is an interesting idea, but unfortunately i'd like the site to work for people landing on a random page from google :)

Answer (score 0):

A blacklist is probably not a good way of doing it, it would be better to have a whitelist of known bots that are allowed to make over a certain amount of hits per second. If someone not on that whitelist makes too many hits per second, start dropping their connections for a few seconds. This will help prevent ddosing, and still let unknown bots scan your site (although a lot slower than the ones you think matter).

You can keep a log of the offenders and see who are breaking the rules repeatedly :)